# Using color functions in a SCSS @each loop

Tags: sass, each

I am trying to create a loop that works off of a map of three values, and use color functions in the output but my code fails to compile as soon as I make use of color functions.

```
$socials:
    "facebook" "#2D88FF" "#FFF",
    "twitter" "#1EA1F1" "#FFF",
    "email" "#BDC6CC" "#424445",
    "copy" "#005269" "#FFF";

@each $name, $bg, $fg in $socials {
    .share__link--#{$name} {
        background-color: $bg;
        color: rgba($fg, .8);
        strong {
            color: $fg;
        }
        &:hover {
            background-color: darken($bg, 2%);
        }
    }
}
```

My compile error:

> Dart Sass failed with this error: Error: $color: "#FFF" is not a color.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

Answering my own question:

My opening array was the issue. Wrapping my colors in quotations was treating them as strings rather than color objects.

**Working code:**

```
$socials:
    "facebook" #2D88FF #FFF,
    "twitter" #1EA1F1 #FFF,
    "email" #BDC6CC #424445,
    "copy" #005269 #FFF;

@each $name, $bg, $fg in $socials {
    .share__link--#{$name} {
        background-color: $bg;
        color: rgba($fg, .8);
        strong {
            color: $fg;
        }
        &:hover {
            background-color: darken($bg, 2%);
        }
    }
}
```